# installation of zendframework 2.2 UnexpectedValueException

Tags: composer-php

I am trying to install zendframework on my windows 7. I have installed wamp and have put ZendFramework-2.2.1_2 folder into wamp/bin/php/php5.*.*/ and added path to library in include_path variable of php. now i am trying to use composer to install the project but it is saying that

```
c:\wamp\www\my_app>cd ZendSkeletonApplication

c:\wamp\www\my_app\ZendSkeletonApplication>php composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing zendframework/zendframework (2.2.1)
    Downloading: 100%



  [UnexpectedValueException]
  'C:\wamp\www\my_app\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor/zendframework/zendframew
  ork/bf2ea22d074d758da4b97aae94293c3a.1' is not a zip archive.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corrupted cache files are the problem.

The solution is to delete the cache files and execute the command again. The cache files are in [the composer home directory](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home):

on windows:

> C:\Users[user]>\AppData\Roaming\Composer
>
> or
>
> C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Composer (I found composer cache files here)

on *nix:

> /home/[user]/.composer

on OSX:

> /Users/[user]/.composer